# Error: The operator '+' isn't defined for the class 'Object'

Tags: dictionary, dart

As a complete Dart beginner coming from python and javascript, I find this behavior quite strange:

```
var user = {'name': 'John Doe', 'birth_y': 1980};
2021-user['birth_y'] // is 41
```

But if the operator is on the right.

```
user['birth_y'] + 41 // error
```

The error:

```
Error: The operator '+' isn't defined for the class 'Object'.
- 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '+' operator.
  user['birth_y'] + 41;
                  ^
```

From the error, one guesses that for maps with mixed types, entries have type 'Object', Yet:

```
user['birth_y'] is int // true
user['birth_y'].runtimeType // int
```

This behavior is also exhibited by lists of mixed types,
What am I missing?

Comment: I can see you are running Dart in pre-null-safety mode. With Dart 2.12's null safety, the `41 + user['birth_y']` will also be an error because you no longer get implicit downcast from `Object` to `num`.

Comment: @lrn Properly also a `null` error since we need to do `user['birth_y']!` (or other null safe measure).

Comment: The `int.+` method takes `num` as argument. It won't complain extra about `41 + (something as Object?)` over `41 + (something as Object)`, it's just not a valid argument, and you don't (any longer) get implicit downcast to the valid argument type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart does a statically analysis of your program before running it. In this analyze phase, it will look at the data type of your variables and see if it is statically safe.

In your case you have this `Map`:

```
var user = {'name': 'John Doe', 'birth_y': 1980};
```

Since your `Map` contains different types of values, Dart will try to see which data type can be used for all your values. In this case, the only thing `String` and `int` shares is the `Object` type. So `user` is being analyzed to be of the type `Map<String, Object>`.

This means that when you get a object from `user`, the only thing the analyzer can be sure about is it is of the type `Object`.

So when you do:

```
user['birth_y'] + 41
```

The analyzer will assume you get a `Object` which does not have the `+` operator.

You should in general not use `Map` as some kind of object which contains different data types. Instead create a `class` which makes it possible to write type safe code.

Comment: Ok I see, thank you very much. (I realized that you could use Map<String, dynamic> which is essentially the default behavior I was expecting, but as you said, it is probably not a great idea to use Dart and not take advantage of typechecking).